# Measurements for port placement

Tags: hardware, case

I'm going to design my own Pi 4 case because the existing cases I've found don't really meet my requirements.  Where can I find complete measurements for port placement?  At https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/README.md are mechanical drawings of the boards from the top only.  I need to know shapes and placements from the sides too.  Does this information exist anywhere?  Will I simply have to pull out the calipers and measure everything?

Comment: Thingiverse (https://www.thingiverse.com/tag:raspberry_pi_4) have a lot of 3D cases for Raspberry, perhaps you can use one of them?!